# Deploy Kafka + Debezium on multi computer

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium

I have problem when connect Kafka Connect and Kafka

I am setting up Kafka + Debezium to sync data between 2 DBMS.
But I don't know how to set up Kafka Connect (on computer A) which Debezium running on it point to Kafka (on computer B)
Kafka and Kafka Connect are also running on Docker

Comment: Debezium / Kafka Connect allow you to set bootstrap servers to any IP / hostname. Sounds like your question is more about networking and configuration rather than a specific technology?